# I am really stuck right now on moving to a different activity from a fragment

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, webrtc

This is my Code for **CallFragment.kt** , when i click on *btnSetupVideoCall* nothing happens whereas i should be going to different activity.

```
class CallFragment : Fragment() {
private var param1: String? = null
private var param2: String? = null
private lateinit var binding: FragmentCallBinding
companion object {
   
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
        CallFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
            }
        }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_call, container, false)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
        param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
        param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
    }

}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding = FragmentCallBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    binding.btnSetupVideoCall.setOnClickListener{
        (activity as MainActivity?)?.let {
            val intent = Intent(it, One_to_One_VC::class.java)
            it.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

}
```

}

And this is how i made fragments in **mainactivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)

    val callFragment = CallFragment()
    val chatFragment = ChatFragment()
    makeCurrentFragment(callFragment)

    binding.btmNvg.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.ic_call -> makeCurrentFragment(callFragment)
            R.id.ic_chat -> makeCurrentFragment(chatFragment)
            else -> makeCurrentFragment(callFragment)
        }
        true
    }

}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if(binding.btmNvg.selectedItemId == R.id.ic_call){
        super.onBackPressed()
        finish()
    }else{
        makeCurrentFragment(CallFragment())
    }

}

private fun makeCurrentFragment(fragment: Fragment) =
   supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
       replace(R.id.fl_wrapper , fragment)
       commit()
   }
```

}

[Logcat when i click the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaReb.png)

The only option left for me is to make another UI since it is starting of the project only but help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

onCreateView should use FragmentCallBinding.inflate

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
       
        binding  =  FragmentCallBinding.inflate(inflater)

return binding.root
}
```

onViewCreated should not assign the binding variable

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
   
    binding.btnSetupVideoCall.setOnClickListener{
        (activity as MainActivity?)?.let {
            val intent = Intent(it, One_to_One_VC::class.java)
            it.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

}
```